How do you get the full coordinates of the current screen in a content script of a Chrome extension?
I'm writing a Manifest v3 Chrome extension where a content script needs to know the dimensions of the screen its window is in. This means the full size of the screen in pixels, not just the "available" area.
In Firefox, I can use a combination of screen.left, screen.top, screen.width, and screen.height.
However, in Chrome, screen.left and screen.top are not available, and instead it only has screen.availLeft and screen.availTop. There's no way that I'm aware of to calculate the screen's proper left and top coordinates given the information Chrome provides in screen's properties.
Is there any way to do this?

Dimensions are already exposed as width and height, no need to calculate them. If you want to find the display's coordinates in a multi-display setup, you can use chrome.system.display.getInfo in the background script and then send the info to the content script.

Looks like chrome.system.display.getInfo is the way to go, along with chrome.system.display.onDisplayChanged. If you like you can submit it as an answer I'll accept it.
